# How can I alter my program to sort a list into descending order by changing ONE operator?

Tags: python, sorting, operators, bubble-sort

So I have this bubble sort algorithm that only worked in **ascending** order, so I am trying to adapt the program by passing *'ascending'* or *'descending'* as a parameter to the function which will change the operator from '>' to '<' when comparing adjacent items in a list. I have tried this, does anyone have any ideas? I would like to keep the code as it is and try and not to add an if statement that repeats the entire code for each condition.

```
array=[5,7,0,4,3,24,-1,83,2,1]

def BubbleSort(alist, order):
    position=0
    swapmade=True
    if order == 'ascending':
        symbol = '>'
    elif order == 'descending':
        symbol = '<'
    while swapmade == True:
        swapmade=False
        for count in range(len(alist)-1):
            LB=alist[position]
            UB=alist[position+1]
            if alist[position] + symbol + alist[position+1]:
                LB,UB=UB,LB
                alist.remove(alist[position+1])
                alist.insert(position, LB)
                swapmade=True
            position=position+1
            if position+1 == len(alist):
                position=0
    return alist

result = BubbleSort(array, 'ascending')
print(*result)
```

Comment: `alist[position] + symbol + alist[position+1]` does not do what you think it does. You want to use `operator.lt` and `operator.gt` instead of strings `'<'` and `'>'`.

Comment: BTW, to swap, you can do this: `alist[position], alist[position+1] = alist[position+1], alist[position]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted to keep the code you had, you can use the operator module to map an operator to a variable.

So instead of setting *symbol* to "<" or ">", you could do this (where gt is greater than and lt is less than)

```
import operator
if order == 'ascending':
    op = operator.gt
elif order == 'descending':
    op = operator.lt
```

and this

```
if op(alist[position], alist[position + 1]):
    LB, UB = UB, LB
    alist.remove(alist[position + 1])
    alist.insert(position, LB)
    swapmade = True
```

Comment: The next obvious step would be to change the function so it doesn't depend on a string parameter to indicate the direction of the sort. Instead, just pass in `operator.gt` or `operator.lt` or any other comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple ways to do what you want.

One way is to define a comparison function that depends on the parameter. Near the beginning of your swap function define

```
comparefunc = (lambda x,y: x < y) if order == 'ascending' else (lambda x,y: x < y)
```

Then use the statement

```
if comparefunc(alist[position], alist[position+1]):
```

A variation on that is to use the predefined comparison functions `gt` and `lt` from the `operator` module (as in @zvone's comment) rather than the `lambda` functions I used, if you are willing to import that module.

Since you are sorting integers, another way is to compare negatives of the values if the sort is to be descending. I'll leave you to figure out that coding.